Numbered Sets of Balls in Bins
For any prime power $N$, suppose we have $N^2+N+1$ indistinguishable bins, $N^2+N+1$ distinct people, and each person has $N+1$ indistinguishable balls.
Each person throws all of their balls into a different bin so that no two balls from the same person are in the same bin. Furthermore, for any two people, there must be exactly one bin that they have both thrown a ball into.
How many ways can this occur?
For the sake of illustration, we can consider each person to be a vector of 1's and 0's such that a 1 indicates where a ball was thrown. Below is a valid (and the only valid way) that it would work for $N=1$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now for $N=2$, I have found that there are exactly $30$ such cases as well as a (potentially) useful fact; each bin must have exactly $N+1$ balls in it.
For $N>2$, I am unable to find an exact answer as the number of possibilities grows quite exponentially. Suppose one were to brute force through all potential combinations, if a satisfiability check was done at the end, there would be $\binom{\binom{N^2+N+1}{N+1}}{N^2+N+1}$ cases to look through....
Surely there must be something that I'm missing here to make this easier to approach?
Here are the $30$ cases for $N=2$ in case it is of any visual help:
1
\begin{align*}
&1110000\\
&1001010\\
&1000101\\
&0101001\\
&0100110\\
&0011100\\
&0010011\\
\end{align*}
2
\begin{align*}
&1100010\\
&1011000\\
&1000101\\
&0110001\\
&0101100\\
&0010110\\
&0001011\\
\end{align*}
3
\begin{align*}
&1110000\\
&1001100\\
&1000011\\
&0101001\\
&0100110\\
&0011010\\
&0010101\\
\end{align*}
4
\begin{align*}
&1100001\\
&1011000\\
&1000110\\
&0110100\\
&0101010\\
&0010011\\
&0001101\\
\end{align*}
5
\begin{align*}
&1100001\\
&1011000\\
&1000110\\
&0110010\\
&0101100\\
&0010101\\
&0001011\\
\end{align*}
6
\begin{align*}
&1101000\\
&1010001\\
&1000110\\
&0110010\\
&0100101\\
&0011100\\
&0001011\\
\end{align*}
7
\begin{align*}
&1110000\\
&1001001\\
&1000110\\
&0101010\\
&0100101\\
&0011100\\
&0010011\\
\end{align*}
8
\begin{align*}
&1101000\\
&1010001\\
&1000110\\
&0110100\\
&0100011\\
&0011010\\
&0001101\\
\end{align*}
9
\begin{align*}
&1110000\\
&1001001\\
&1000110\\
&0101100\\
&0100011\\
&0011010\\
&0010101\\
\end{align*}
10
\begin{align*}
&1101000\\
&1010100\\
&1000011\\
&0110001\\
&0100110\\
&0011010\\
&0001101\\
\end{align*}
11
\begin{align*}
&1100100\\
&1010001\\
&1001010\\
&0111000\\
&0100011\\
&0010110\\
&0001101\\
\end{align*}
12
\begin{align*}
&1110000\\
&1001100\\
&1000011\\
&0101010\\
&0100101\\
&0011001\\
&0010110\\
\end{align*}
13
\begin{align*}
&1100100\\
&1011000\\
&1000011\\
&0110001\\
&0101010\\
&0010110\\
&0001101\\
\end{align*}
14
\begin{align*}
&1100100\\
&1011000\\
&1000011\\
&0110010\\
&0101001\\
&0010101\\
&0001110\\
\end{align*}
15
\begin{align*}
&1101000\\
&1010100\\
&1000011\\
&0110010\\
&0100101\\
&0011001\\
&0001110\\
\end{align*}
16
\begin{align*}
&1100001\\
&1010100\\
&1001010\\
&0111000\\
&0100110\\
&0010011\\
&0001101\\
\end{align*}
17
\begin{align*}
&1100001\\
&1010100\\
&1001010\\
&0110010\\
&0101100\\
&0011001\\
&0000111\\
\end{align*}
18
\begin{align*}
&1100100\\
&1010001\\
&1001010\\
&0110010\\
&0101001\\
&0011100\\
&0000111\\
\end{align*}
19
\begin{align*}
&1100010\\
&1011000\\
&1000101\\
&0110100\\
&0101001\\
&0010011\\
&0001110\\
\end{align*}
20
\begin{align*}
&1110000\\
&1001010\\
&1000101\\
&0101100\\
&0100011\\
&0011001\\
&0010110\\
\end{align*}
21
\begin{align*}
&1100010\\
&1010100\\
&1001001\\
&0110001\\
&0101100\\
&0011010\\
&0000111\\
\end{align*}
22
\begin{align*}
&1100010\\
&1010100\\
&1001001\\
&0111000\\
&0100101\\
&0010011\\
&0001110\\
\end{align*}
23
\begin{align*}
&1101000\\
&1010010\\
&1000101\\
&0110100\\
&0100011\\
&0011001\\
&0001110\\
\end{align*}
24
\begin{align*}
&1101000\\
&1010010\\
&1000101\\
&0110001\\
&0100110\\
&0011100\\
&0001011\\
\end{align*}
25
\begin{align*}
&1100100\\
&1010010\\
&1001001\\
&0110001\\
&0101010\\
&0011100\\
&0000111\\
\end{align*}
26
\begin{align*}
&1100010\\
&1010001\\
&1001100\\
&0110100\\
&0101001\\
&0011010\\
&0000111\\
\end{align*}
27
\begin{align*}
&1100010\\
&1010001\\
&1001100\\
&0111000\\
&0100101\\
&0010110\\
&0001011\\
\end{align*}
28
\begin{align*}
&1100001\\
&1010010\\
&1001100\\
&0110100\\
&0101010\\
&0011001\\
&0000111\\
\end{align*}
29
\begin{align*}
&1100001\\
&1010010\\
&1001100\\
&0111000\\
&0100110\\
&0010101\\
&0001011\\
\end{align*}
30
\begin{align*}
&1100100\\
&1010010\\
&1001001\\
&0111000\\
&0100011\\
&0010101\\
&0001110\\
\end{align*}

The title says the balls are numbered, but the body says the balls are indistinguishable. That's a contradiction. Please edit for consistency.

@GerryMyerson it should be better now. The Sets of balls each have a distinct 'number' as they are tied to a different person even though each ball from a person is indistinguishable.

@RobertShore that's actually how I brute force coded N=2

My only thought is to convert this to a matrix theory problem.  Define the matrix $A$ via $(a_{ij})=1$ if person $i$ has a ball in bin $j$, $0$ otherwise.  Then $AA^T=E+nI$, where $E$ is the $(n^2+n+1) \times (n^2+n+1)$ matrix of all $1$s.  The question then becomes how many possible matrices $A$ are there satisfying this equation.  I don't know whether framing the question this way makes it any easier, but it's all I've got.  Since you're assuming that $n$ is a power of a prime $p$, note that $AA^T \equiv E \pmod p$, which makes it singular in that field.

Also, since the bins are indistinguishable, you can permute columns to your heart's content, so without loss of generality, the first row starts with $n+1$ consecutive $1$s.

For what it's worth, the matrices you wind up with can be interpreted as incidence matrices for projective planes of order $N$, with a row for each line and a column for each point.

The number of ways is
$$
\sum_{P} \frac{(N^2+N+1)!}{|\text{Aut}(P)|},
$$
where $P$ ranges over all isomorphism classes of projective planes of order $N$.
It is in general an open problem to enumerate all non-isomorphic projective planes of order $N$, let alone determine the size of their automorphism groups. However, for all prime powers $N\ge 2$, there always exists the plane $\mathrm{PG}(2,N)$; the points of this space are linear subspaces of $\mathbb F_N^3$, and the lines are two-dimensional subspaces. The fundamental theorem of projective geometry gives us the structure of this automorphism group:
$$
\text{Aut}(\mathrm{PG}(2,N))=PGL(3,N)\ltimes \text{Aut}(\mathbb F_N).
$$
Here, $PGL(3,N)$ is the group of linear transformations on $\mathbb F_N^3$ with determinant one, while $\text{Aut}(\mathbb F_N)$ is just the Galois group of $\mathbb F_N$ over its prime subfield. Writing $N=p^k$ for a prime $p$ and integer $k$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
|PGL(3,N)|&=\frac{(N^3-1)(N^3-N)(N^3-N^2)}{N-1}\\
&= (N^2+N+1)(N^2+N)(N^2)(N-1)^2,\\\\
|\text{Aut}(\mathbb F_N)|&=k.
\end{align}
$$
This fully answers your question in the case where $2\le N\le 8$, because in these cases it is known that the only projective plane is $\mathrm{PG}(2,N)$. For example:

When $N=2$, we have $|PGL(3,2)|=7\cdot 6\cdot 4\cdot 1$, and $|\text{Aut}(\mathbb F_2)|=1$, so the number of ways is ${7!}/({7\cdot 6\cdot 4})=30$.

When $N=3$, we have $|PGL(3,3)|=13\cdot 12\cdot 9\cdot 4$, and $|\text{Aut}(\mathbb F_3)|=1$, so the number of ways is ${13!}/({13\cdot 12\cdot 9\cdot 4})=1108800$.

When $N=4$, we have $|PGL(3,4)|=21\cdot 20\cdot 16\cdot 9$, and $|\text{Aut}(\mathbb F_4)|=2$, so the number of ways is ${21!}/({21\cdot 20\cdot 16\cdot 9\cdot 2})=422378820864000$.


However, for $N=9$, there are four non-isomorphic projective planes of order $9$.
Proof of formula
Your problem is equivalent to counting $\{0,1\}$-matrices with dimensions $(N^2+N+1)\times (N^2+N+1)$, with $N+1$ ones in each row and column, such that any two rows share a one in a unique column. Furthermore, you are only counting matrices up to a permutation of the rows. It is well-known that such a matrix is necessarily the incidence matrix of a projective plane. Let us fix a plane $P$ and count all matrices whose structure is isomorphic to $P$.
Let $M_0$ be a particular matrix whose structure is $P$. This means that every matrix isomorphic to $P$ can be obtained by permuting the columns of $M_0$ in one of $(N^2+N+1)!$ ways. However, not all of these permutations produce distinct squares. Let $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ be two permutations of the columns of $M_0$ which result in equivalent matrices; this means there exist row permutations $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ for which $\rho_1\circ\pi_1(M_0)=\rho_2\circ\pi_2 (M_0)$. Since row and column permutations commute, we get that $(\rho_1\rho_2^{-1})\circ (\pi_1\pi_2^{-1})(M_0)=M_0$. It follows that $\pi_1\pi_2^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $P$. This means that the unique matrices correspond exactly to the cosets of the full permtutation group $S_{N^2+N+1}$ with respect to the subgroup $\text{Aut}(P)$, so the number of matrices is $(N^2+N+1)!/|\text{Aut}(P)|$. Since every matrix is isomorphic to some $P$, we conclude by summing over $P$.

This was a really detailed answer, thanks so much!

For $N=3$, this formula gives $739200$. The sequence does not appear to be in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. I'm surprised.

@GerryMyerson I had a mistake, and the actual number for $N=3$ was $1108800$, but you are right that this is not in OEIS. I guess the number of non-equivalent ways to label the vertices of a projective plane is not an interesting sequence.

It's amusing that OEIS has six entries for $422378820864000$, but not this one.
